# Proxmox high RAM usage

Tags: memory, proxmox

I'm currently running a Proxmox PC with 16GB of RAM. This system hosts 2 VMs and 1 LXC.

- VM-1: This VM is allocated 6GB of RAM and runs Jellyfin along with other ARR projects.
- VM-2: This VM is allocated 10GB of RAM and is used for a Minecraft server. Note that the Minecraft server is assigned 6GB of RAM.

However, I'm facing an issue where my Proxmox server is using almost all of its RAM (around 14GB out of 16GB), as shown in the Proxmox RAM status. But the RAM usage inside the VMs tells a different story:

- VM-1 (Debian 12) is using 2.15GB out of 6GB. [image](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/786568002727837717/1182409277034475540/image.png?ex=65849773&is=65722273&hm=bf3294fb1ad3cf0c935014204ff8222d4707e04ef5ec078f469ffd0c68f7b679&=&format=webp&quality=lossless) || [vm config](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/786568002727837717/1182417654078775346/image.png?ex=65849f40&is=65722a40&hm=c983f5d71e9b28aa8dc6bd79dacb960b7afd1e85bbb9b169550ccd3d80cb9760&=&format=webp&quality=lossless)
- VM-2 (Debian 12) is using 7.3GB out of 10GB. [image](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/786568002727837717/1182409154221060138/image.png?ex=65849756&is=65722256&hm=1b24990d6554ef2eda18126e61012730ab0c6e8767d0d4b3895caefbea0b37fd&=&format=webp&quality=lossless) || [vm config](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/786568002727837717/1182417697284296735/image.png?ex=65849f4b&is=65722a4b&hm=e200548a1d1ef634fe7e33ca601c021cf31d21d30bdf0b772aa2418c79033e71&=&format=webp&quality=lossless)
- The LXC, which just contains Caddy, uses around 50MB of RAM.

So, according to my calculations, the total RAM usage should be around 11GB (Proxmox 1.5GB + VM-1 2.15GB + VM-2 7.3GB). I'm unable to account for an extra 2GB of usage. Moreover, sometimes the Proxmox webUI status shows 15.5GB RAM usage, so I'm unsure what's using the leftover 3/4GB of RAM. This issue is causing other applications inside all VMs to sometimes not respond.

For reference, here's what I'm running in my VMs (all are Docker containers):

- VM-1: ​[[VM1 Docker Containers](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/786568002727837717/1182414556979531908/image.png?ex=65849c5e&is=6572275e&hm=60d0e7101b1e3073284c4f89c8dd8aa9be26edcb0fb0b2ac350c7bc09682a67d&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=721&height=676)]
- VM-2: [[VM2 Docker Containers](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/786568002727837717/1182414553766707371/image.png?ex=65849c5d&is=6572275d&hm=611142569423b47b057c932197ca0f58cb23ef77d417f275eacccb5e14c13184&=&format=webp&quality=lossless)]

My Proxmox PC configuration is as follows:

- CPU: i5-4590 (4c 4t)
- RAM: 8*2 1333hz DDR3
- Motherboard: Gigabyte H81
- Drive: 120GB SSD for boot & 12TB HDD for storage

I'm looking for a solution to this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

Approximately similar RAM usage from the proxmox and the VMS together

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of command, on the host machine, `cat /proc/meminfo`   Need to look at what total memory use actually is, rather than only summing up its workloads.